# How to access a JavaScript object from outside of the variable

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I have JavaScript object in a variable which I'm trying to access from outside of it. It's current form just alerts the entire function's code. I know this is an issue to do with variable scope.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qKJag/)

How do I alert, for example, the name for id 1?

```
var LocalStorage = function() {
    var queries = [
        {id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 28},
        {id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 18},
        {id: 3, name: "Miles", age: 28},
    ];
}

var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert(LocalStorage);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Comment: What's the point of having the `LocalStorage` function in the first place? Why not define the array in the right scope?

Comment: I know that would make more sense. However, in the final application I want LocalStorage to be in a file on its own. I just simplified it all for the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign the variables as properties of the object itself.

```
var LocalStorage = new (function() {
    this.queries = [
        {id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 28},
        {id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 18},
        {id: 3, name: "Miles", age: 28},
    ];
    this.foo = "Bar";
})()

var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert(LocalStorage.queries[0].name); //Alerts "Mike"
        alert(LocalStorage.foo); //Alerts "bar"
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qKJag/7/

Comment: you should edit Mihails and delete this answer when your edit is accepted

Comment: Well, I had originally mentioned his answer because I thought he was the one that made the fiddle; just now noticed that it came for original post.  I think the content of mine is distinctly different from his answer.  (And both are working solutions)

Comment: I see, I agreed that your method makes it more useful since you can assign more than just one var to be accessed within LocalStorage but thought it was something you thought of after seeing Mihails's solution but you argue it wasn't and I can't disprove that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var LocalStorage = new (function() {
    var queries = [
        {id: 1, name: "Mike", age: 28},
        {id: 2, name: "Jane", age: 18},
        {id: 3, name: "Miles", age: 28},
    ];
    return queries
})()

var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert(LocalStorage[0].id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qKJag/3/

But it is no so good way. If you will use only Array, than you not need make function LocalStorage.